# how can i fix nullity JSON problems?

Tags: jquery, json, zend-framework2

I have the next problem, i can't get the JSON value,im working on ZF2 (MVC) , and i have the next problem  SyntaxError: Unexpected token N , thats mean im sending a null value WHY? someone solution

```
$(".bajaAlumno").click(function(){
    var dat= $(this).attr('id');
    var response = '{"name":"'+dat+'"}';
        $.ajax({
            url:'bajaAlumnos',
            dataType:'json',
            data:response,  
            type:'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },

           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: What's its relation to zf2?

Comment: i.m working with that technology

Answer (score 0):

Place a space before and after your attribute name, example:

```
{  "Name": "value" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/patelmilanb1/6Ea6C/

```
$(".bajaAlumno").click(function () {
    var dat = "Neville";
    var response = '{"name":"' + dat + '"}';
    alert(response);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bajaAlumnos',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(response),
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

its showing alert fine in jsfiddle...

Update: have a look at this SO question for posting data to ZF2 controller

[Posting Form Data to ZF2 Controller With Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480297/posting-form-data-to-zf2-controller-with-ajax)

For your example, you first need to enable the JSON view strategy by adding it to your view manager config (typically in module.config.php):

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy'
    )
),
```

[ZF2 View strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534327/zf2-view-strategy)

Comment: did not get your comment.. could you please explian

Comment: i would like to know how i can get the json value  in the zf2 controler

Comment: have a look at this SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480297/posting-form-data-to-zf2-controller-with-ajax